# Rendered Animation Not Working, Stays on Frame 0

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine

Newbie here.
I am trying to render a simple animation but blender is not working. Need help on understanding what are the additional things I need to set up. Whenever I render an MPEG4 video, the details in the view is not moving: [image] . It just stays on frame 0. I also went to 'Render-View Animation' if there was any animation produced, but it says 'File ..... not found'.

These are my current project state:

- OpenCL: AMD Radeon RX 560 Series
- Blender: 2.93.9
- Frames: 1-100
- Output Properties:

[image]

- Render Properties

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome, are you sure that you rendered the animation (CTRL + F12) or just rendered the current frame (F12) ?

Comment: I'm with @Emir on this one. It is questionable why it says frame 0 for example, since your animation ranges from 1 to 100. So even if it would only render the first frame, this would be 1, not 0. Rendering frames outside the animation range is only possible with single image rendering F12. So, did you really render the animation with Ctrl+F12?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Ok, check if E/video/ is a real folder without restrictions, go there and create a text file. It excludes the option that blender cant write.

2 - If folder is ok the next problem I would look is video codec, you can try medium quality and good, instead of perceptual lossless and slowest (they could be requesting more memory than the avaliable.

3 - If video codec alone changes nothing the combination of container and video codec could change MPEG-4 + H.264 is very good, but Quicktime + QT is a good test to this problem too.

4 - I really want to reccomend more tecnichal changes, but if you haven't a good reason to use blender version less than 3.00 an update can help too.